# Accordeon doesn´t work with jquery and bootstrap

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have an accordeon in my web, but when i click them, it does nothing, it just moves down, even though I have jquery and bootstrap activated, could it be that it is conflicting with another jquery? since my site is in wordpress

```
$.fn.jquery ( JQuery )
'1.12.4'
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION ( Bootstrap )
'4.5.3'
```

I check by console the versions that I have

and the example code in my web:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#balances" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="balances">
          <h1 data-uw-styling-context="true">BALANCES</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="balances" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- TEXT HERE -->
        <div class="panel-group" id="sub-accordion_3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="subHeadingThree">
              <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-accordion_3" href="#balances_2011" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="balances_2011" data-uw-styling-context="true">
                  2011 - 2015
                </a>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="balances_2011" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="HeadingSubThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- TEXT HERE -->  
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <tbody>           
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="sitio.com/wp-content/files_mf/1452701875Balance2011.pdf" target="_blank" class="gestionlink2" data-uw-styling-context="true">2011</a><a href="https://docreader.readspeaker.com/docreader/?cid=cbhig&amp;lang=es_us&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.museodelamemoria.cl%2Fwp-content%2Ffiles_mf%2F1452701875Balance2011.pdf" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" class="rspkr_dr_link" target="_blank" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px;"><img src="https://media.readspeaker.com/images/buttons/listen_icons/icon_16px.gif" alt="Abrir este documento usando ReadSpeaker docReader" title="Abrir este documento usando ReadSpeaker docReader" class="rspkr_dr_img" style="border: 0px; display: inline; margin: 0px; position: absolute;"></a>
                                    </td>...
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/Amaroak/pen/bGrQpPj

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work here in a snippet or on jsfiddle (or a complete codepen)?

Comment: Maybe it's because you have bunch of DIV's on top and actual Accordion is inside those DIV's? Try to make your contents inside accordion.

Comment: Doest work in a snippet, jsfiddle, or codepen, even in my website doesn't work. 
I also do not find what versions I need to make the accordeon work, or what other elements I should call, such as Jquery, Bootstrap,etc.